How to optimize the query with subquery and sum Mysql?
Have a nice day. I have the following query that takes me a long time to execute:
SELECT
    formapago.codigos,
    formapago.cuentacte AS cargos,
    IFNULL(
        (SELECT SUM(IF(referencias.tipodoc IN (00,61),
                        referencias.valor,
                        referencias.valor*-1
                        ) - IFNULL((SELECT SUM(IF(ref.tipodoc IN (56),ref.valor,ref.valor*-1)) 
                                                        FROM referencias ref 
                                                        WHERE ref.empresa IN(SELECT codigo 
                                                                            FROM intituciones 
                                                                            WHERE codigos = 76291019) 
                                                        AND ref.codigos = referencias.codigos 
                                                        AND ref.tipodoc IN(56,61) 
                                                        AND ref.tipodocref = referencias.tipodoc 
                                                        AND ref.numerodocref = referencias.numerodoc),0)) 
        FROM referencias 
        WHERE referencias.empresa IN (SELECT codigo 
                                        FROM intituciones 
                                        WHERE codigos = 76291019) 
        AND referencias.codigos = formapago.codigos 
        AND referencias.tipodoc IN(00,56,61) 
        AND referencias.tipodocref = formapago.tipodoc 
        AND referencias.numerodocref = formapago.numerodoc),0) AS abonos 
FROM formapago 
LEFT JOIN condicionesp ON IF(formapago.condiciondep=0,1,formapago.condiciondep)=condicionesp.codigo 
LEFT JOIN clientes ON formapago.codigos = clientes.codigos 
WHERE formapago.empresa = 2 
AND formapago.codigos = 77155568 
AND formapago.tipodoc IN (33,34,35,39) 
AND formapago.cuentacte <> 0 
HAVING cargos<>abonos

It takes about 20 seconds
I needed to know if there is a possibility of optimizing the query, perhaps changing some way of obtaining the subqueries could be.
The table that I put institutions on is the same one called companies, in the photo it appears

Any help is appreciated, Greetings and thank you for your attention.

Are there indices on the table, especially on the fields you select on? What does the explain command say?

@Robert It already has indexes, but I don't know that explain command, nor have I used it.

Firstly - replace WHERE IN with INNER JOIN or at least with WHERE EXISTS. Then - "using where" in your execution plan tells that index scan (instead of index seek) is used, try to optimize this points, create according indices.

Please run EXPLAIN ANALYZE for your query and update your question with the output https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-explain-analyze/

Hi Carmen, I saw your request right after seeing the similar request in Spanish posted two days ago by Danilo here: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/617698/c%c3%b3mo-poder-optimizar-la-consulta-sql. I appreciate your effort of posting this in English, so I have posted a short answer here, but in order to practise my Spanish I posted a longer answer over there. (Mainly complaining about the weird data model with all those codigos in singular and plural that make it hard to understand.)

You want an index to get quickly to the formapagos in question. You are looking for a specific codigos, and I assume that this column is rather selective, i.e. not too many rows share the same codigo. This is the index I am suggesting:
create index idx1 on formapago(codigos, empresa, tipodoc, cuentacte)

Then, with the formapago you select related referencias, and with these referenias, you select sub-referencias using the same columns. Here is the index on those columns, again starting with codigos which I assume to be the most selective column.
create index idx2 on referencias(codigos, numerodocref, tipodocref, tipodoc, empresa)

Always try to create indexes such that they start with the most selective columns (i.e. the columns that most narrow down the results).
Additionally you have two outer joins, but you are not using the tables in your query, so just delete the two lines:
LEFT JOIN condicionesp ON IF(formapago.condiciondep=0,1,formapago.condiciondep)=condicionesp.codigo 
LEFT JOIN clientes ON formapago.codigos = clientes.codigos 

